# Azure ML workspace: how to publish pipeline to existing endpoint instead of creating new

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

I'm working on deploying an inference pipeline in Azure machine learning workspace.

I have created a pipeline using a couple of `PythonScriptStep`s and want to automate the pipeline publishing using CI/CD.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-pipelines#publish-a-pipeline

```py
pipeline = Pipeline(workspace=workspace, steps=[step1, step2])
pipeline_endpoint = pipeline.publish(name='deployment-test', version=1)
```

Every time I publish, it is creating new endpoints but I want to deploy to existing so that nothing has to be changed in the consumer end.

Comment: The Azure documentation of the versioned pipeline endpoint is not correct currently. For more information, see this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/59931).

Answer (score 4):

[`PipelineEndpoint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-pipeline-core/azureml.pipeline.core.pipelineendpoint?view=azure-ml-py) can be used to update a published pipeline while maintaining the same endpoint. `PipelineEndpoint` provides a way to keep track of [`PublishedPipeline`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-pipeline-core/azureml.pipeline.core.publishedpipeline?view=azure-ml-py)s using versions. `PipelineEndpoint` uses endpoint with version information to trigger an underlying published pipeline. Pipeline endpoints are uniquely named within a workspace.

Comment: Problem with PipelineEndpoint is that I cannot get the run history as run history is tied to a pipeline. Is it possible to get run history from PipeLineEndpoint? Additionally, Azure ML cli does not support PipelineEndpoint which makes it harder to deploy new pipelines using CI/CD.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem as you and managed to get it to work by doing the following:

First initialize the endpoint:

```
pipeline = Pipeline(workspace=ws, steps=steps)
published = pipeline.publish(
            name="name"
        )
pipeline_endpoint = PipelineEndpoint.publish(
            workspace=ws,
            name="My endpoint name",
            pipeline=published,
            description="Endpoint to my pipeline",
       )
pipeline_endpoint.add_default(published)
```

The next time you run this you instead run:

```
pipeline = Pipeline(workspace=ws, steps=steps)
published = pipeline.publish(
            name="name"
)
pipeline_endpoint = PipelineEndpoint.get(
     workspace=ws, name="My endpoint name"
)
pipeline_endpoint.add_default(published)
```

add_default makes sure that the latest version of the pipeline is used in the endpoint.

Comment: But there's no way to republish a PipelineEndpoint without first publishing the Pipeline run? My use case is that I'd like to republish a pipeline definition (the Pipeline() object) without having to publish a run of the pipeline before publishing it as a PipelineEndpoint

Comment: For example, you can submit `PipelineEndpoint.publish(workspace, pipeline=Pipeline(workspace, steps=[step1, step2]), name='pipeline_name')`, but you can't later add a new pipeline definition using `PipelineEndpoint.add_default(Pipeline(workspace, steps=[step1, step2]))` .add_default ONLY accepts PublishedPipeline objects